# Making a loop with lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, printing, count

I am new to Python and would like to create a print function that repeats itself for each item in a list (this is only an example my actual code will be for something else)

```
cars.list = [Honda, Chevrolet, Suzuki, Ford]

price.list = [5600, 11500, 6600, 1020]
```

The prices and car lists are in the same order so Honda is $5600, Chevrolet is 11500 ect. I'd like it to run a loop for each of the cars that prints this:

```
while count in cars.list:
       print("The car type is" Honda/Chev ect. "The price is" 5600, 11500 ect"
```

I want it to repeat the loop for as many cars are in the `cars.list`, as I will add an option for the user to add more cars so the program cannot rely on knowing the specific cars in a list and copying the print statement for each one. It needs to repeat the print statement for every car, replacing the price and car type each time with the next one in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to associate the cars and prices together in an iterator of tuples, then iterate over those tuples while printing what you want.

```
cars = ['Honda', 'Chevrolet', 'Suzuki', 'Ford']
prices = [5600, 11500, 6600, 1020]

for car, price in zip(cars, prices):
    print('The car type is {} and the price is {}.'.format(car, price))
```

**Output:**

```
The car type is Honda and the price is 5600.
The car type is Chevrolet and the price is 11500.
The car type is Suzuki and the price is 6600.
The car type is Ford and the price is 1020.
```

Comment: Thanks Karin,
Im quite new to Python, could you tell me how zip and tuples work and why it allows that to happen. :) Forgive my noobness

Comment: There is a link to `zip` in the answer that links to the Python docs. A tuple is basically like an immutable sequence. Basically when you call `zip(cars, prices)`, the structure returned is an iterator (think of it as something you can step through) of tuples: `[('Honda', 5600), ('Chevrolet', 11500), ...]`. Then in the `for` loop, we iterate over that list, having the "car" part of the tuple (the first element of the tuple) assigned to variable `car`, and the "price" part of the tuple (the second element) assigned to variable `price`. This lets us print a string based on these two values.

Comment: Hey Karin, How would i allow zip to pair maby 3 lists together or more? also how does the program know to repeat the code as many times as items in the list? Im needing to repeat other code as many times as items in a list, suchs as while/if code that repeats for each item in a list, retrieving the info for the same place in the list for all lists. This is because in list 1 for item one it runs the code and retrieves place 1 from all the other lists for use in this code.

Comment: I'd recommend posting this as another question. The comments sections aren't meant for this.